# Error al crear un objeto desde un json con javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, objeto

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web para fin de curso y me estoy desesperando porque quiero pasar los datos de un usuario a una ventana modal, para posteriormente poder modificarlos.

Tengo una tabla con todos los usuarios y un botón modificar en cada línea de usuario. Al pulsar el botón de modificar, quiero que se muestre ese usuario en un modal.

Lo he intentado de varias formas y esta última creo que sería la más correcta pero no sé porque me da error al convertir el json que recibo en un objeto.

He puesto un console.log para el json y otro para el objeto y puedo comprobar que el json lo recibe bien, pero luego da error en el objeto:

```javascript
{"UserId":"27","UserName":"AntonioLopez","Email":"antonio@gmail.com","Password":"9638521","Status":"Alta","Rol":"Admin","FullName":null,"Adress":null,"ZipCode":null,"City":null,"Country":null,"BankCardNumber":null}
```

```
    VM149:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 8
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Object.success (modaluser.js:22:30)
        at c (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:28327)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:29072)
        at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:79901)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:82355)
    success @ modaluser.js:22
    c @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    fireWith @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    l @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    load (async)
    send @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @ modaluser.js:9
    dispatch @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    v.handle @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
```

**gestionUsuarios.php**

```
        <div class="cuerpo" >
        
        <h1><span class="subtitulo">Gestion de Usuarios</span></h1>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
          <table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
            <tr >
              <td class="primera_fila">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Id&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="primera_fila">Usuario</td>
              <td class="primera_fila">Email</td>
              <td class="primera_fila">Password</td>
              <td class="primera_fila">&nbsp;Estado&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="primera_fila">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rol&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              </tr> 
           
          <?php 
         //registros es el array donde tengo guardadas todas los registros y persona será 
          una variable que recorre el array
           while($persona=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
          ?>    
            <tr>
              <td id="id<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"><?php echo $persona["UserId"]?> 
              </td>
              <td id="nombre<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"><?php echo 
              $persona["UserName"]?></td>
              <td id="email<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"><?php echo $persona["Email"]?> 
              </td>
              <td id="password<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>">*******</td>
              <td id="status<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"><?php echo $persona["Status"]? 
              ></td>
              <td id="rol<?php echo $row['userid']; ?>"><?php echo $persona["Rol"]?></td>
        
             <td class="bot" id="del"><a href="#"><input type="button" data-open="modal2" 
             data-target="$persona['UserId']" name='del' id='del' value='Borrar'></td>
             <td class="bot" id="up"><a href="#" ><input type="button"  id="<?php echo 
              $persona['UserId']; ?>" class="mod_user" name='up' id='up' 
              usercod="<?php echo $persona['UserId']; ?>" value="Modificar"></a></td>
            </tr>    
        
           <?php 
             endwhile;
           ?> 
               <!--Ventana Modal para Actualizar--->
             <?php  include('modal/modalusuarios.php'); ?>
        
                        
        <!--ventana para Update modalusuarios.php --->
        <div class="modal" id="modal1">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <div>
                <h3>Ficha del Usuario</h3>
              </div>
              <button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> 
                <p>Cerrar</p> 
              </button>
            </div>
            <section class="modal-content">
                <div style="width: 500px;" class="form-group">
                    <form action="" method="post" name="form_mod_user" id="form_mod_user" 
                    accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); 
                    modificarUser();">      
                            <input type="hidden" id="UserId" name="UserId" requeried>
                            <input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" 
                             class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del usuario" 
                             required><br>
                            <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="form- 
                             control" placeholder="Email del usuario" required><br>
                            <input type="text" id="txtStatus" name="txtStatus" 
                             class="form-control" placeholder="Estado " required><br>
                            <input type="text" id="txtRol" name="txtRol" class="form- 
                             control" placeholder="Rol" required ><br>
                            <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="modif_user" 
                             requeried>
                            <div class="alert    alertModifUser"><p>Alerta acción</p> 
                            </div>
                        </form>
                           <div id="btn">   
                            <button type="button" class="btnFooter"                           
                            name="bot_actualizar" id="bot_actualizar">Modificar</button> 
                           </div>
                      </div>
                   </section>
                 </div>
               </div>
        
        <!---fin ventana Update --->
```

**modaluser.js**

```
//Modal para modificar usuario utilizando Jquery y Ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mod_user").click(function() {
    var usuario = $(this).attr('usercod');
    var accion = 'consultarUsuario';

    //Recuperar los datos del usuario a través de ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: 'modUser.php', //Manda a este archivo para crear la consulta en la base de datos
      type: 'POST', //método post     
      async: true, //Asincrónico
      data: {
        accion: accion,
        usuario: usuario
      },
      success: function(response) {

        console.log(response);

        if (response != 'error') {
          var object = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(object);
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**modUser.php**

```
<?php 
    include "baseDatos.php";

    if (!empty($_POST)) { //Existe un post
        // Extraer datos del usuario
        //Hacemos la conexión con la base de datos 
        $database = "techstore_db";
        $con = crearConexion($database);

        if($_POST['accion'] == 'consultarUsuario'){
            $idUser=$_POST['usuario'];
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UserId=$idUser"); 
                            
            if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                //Se crea un array asociativo
                $data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                //devuelvo en formato json
                echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//Para las tildes y caracteres especiales
            } else {
                //Mensaje de error
                echo 'error';
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Diria que este error: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 8` te está diciendo que hay un caracter `<` dentro del JSON, que yo no veo en tu primera línea.  Quizás te está devolviendo otra cosa en lugar del JSON... ¿Estas segura que puedes hacer el `console.log(object);` y verlo correcto?  Diria que no... ¿y que es lo que ves cuando haces el `console.log(response);`? ¿La primera línea de tu pregunta?

Comment: Revisa la pestaña network en devtools para al menos saber qué te responde el backend. Mi apuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561556/syntax-error-unexpected-token/18561794#18561794

Comment: Pongo aquí lo que me responde solo para el json {"UserId":"27","UserName":"AntonioLopez","Email":"antonio@gmail.com","Password":"9638521","Status":"Alta","Rol":"Admin","FullName":null,"Adress":null,"ZipCode":null,"City":null,"Country":null,"BankCardNumber":null}

Comment: He mirado otra vez lo que recibe y no hay ningún caracter < Pongo arriba otra linea con lo que me sale. Tambien he mirado en network en devtools y no soy capaz de vez en esa pestaña nada sobre el json me salen las columnas con Name, status type.... pero no veo ninguna línea que ponga type json.